# Killing a process with swift programmatically

Tags: swift, process, kill-process

I am trying to find a way to identify and kill specific processes in a Mac Application. Is there a built-in class that has functions that can return the list of running processes? There is one way of running terminal commands using `Process()` and execute the `/usr/bin/killall` command to kill processes but I need to do it programmatically as running terminal commands using an application is not a good practice. For example, deleting a file can also be done by running a terminal command using `Process()` while the better way to do it is using `FileManager.default.remomveItem()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for an application (rather than a process), then see `NSWorkspace.shared.runningApplications`. You can call `terminate()` or `forceTerminate()` on those elements.

If you want a list of all BSD processes (what you would get from a call to `ps` for example), that's done with [sysctl](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa2001/qa1123.html) (the code in the Q&A is in C; you'd have to wrap it to Swift, or rewrite it). I don't believe there's any Cocoa wrapper for that. To kill a process, once you have its PID, use [`signal`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/signal.3.html), which is what the `kill` Unix command uses. Typically you want to send SIGTERM, which is a normal shutdown. To force-kill a process, send SIGKILL.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the pid of the process, you can simply call the kill(::) function:

```
kill(pid, SIGTERM)
```